# Clean-up during component destruction (ColdFusion)

Tags: session, coldfusion, cfc

I have some objects stored in Cache via `putCache()`
The objects in cache have a timeout of 10 minutes.

These objects are shared among all users. However, there are 2-3 variables that are user-dependant.
Currently each object stores these user-dependant variables in the user session.

**Problem:**

When the component is removed from cache after 10 minutes the variables in user session are not deleted. 
So maybe after 12 minutes the object is created again and will write 2 new variables to user session
*Note:* Each object will create a *new* struct in session-scope with an *unique name*. The old variables cannot be overwritten since the new object does not know the struct name of the previous object.

Example: Object is "list.cfc" there can be 20 different lists, each stores completely different data. In session we only store the "list_position" of the current user; the list_items are stored in cache and are same for all users.

We want to clean the session-variables when an object is destroyed. How can this be done?

The idea: In php I would use the `__destruct()` method, but I could not find an equivalent of this in ColdFusion.

Comment: Have you considered storing those objects in the application or server scope so they don't have to be destroyed an re-created?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, but we cannot change this. There are over 100 Applications running (with up to 200 sessions per application) and each Application has several thousand objects. Only about a hundred objects are used by a specific module, so we use cache to free the memory when users change the module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the easiest way is to abstract the naming of your session variables so that you `can` reference them directly. EG: it sounds like currently you have this:

```
// in Cache.cfc
// [...]
someVarInTheCache = sessionReference[uniqueKey]
```

And your object doesn't know that key?

Can you not just do this:

```
someVarInTheCache = sessionReference.someVarRepresentingTheCache[uniqueKey]
```

And then when you kill the Cache, you just kill `session.someVarRepresentingTheCache`, and don't need to know the key.